# Redirect 301 with directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I create some rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/(.*).html$ /dir2/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My old links was look that: `http://example.org/app_name/dir1/dir2/slug.html`, but new links will be looks like: `http://example.org/app_name/dir2/slug`

My redirection works almost good but new links redirect to `http://example.org/dir2/slug` (without app_name/)

How to add app_name/ dir to redirection dynamicaly?

Soluttion below it's not good:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/(.*).html$ /app_name/dir2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra capture before `dir1/dir2`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/dir1/dir2/(.*).html$ /$1/dir2/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/dir1/(.*)/(.*).html$ /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Will generates captured appname, dir2 and the slug

Comment: How is `app_name` dynamic if you have it hardcoded?

Comment: @arco444 i missed to see the __How to add app_name/ dir to redirection dynamicaly?__ line